# PDF to byte array and vice versa

Tags: java, arrays, pdf

I need to convert pdf to byte array and vice versa.

Can any one help me?

This is how I am converting to byte array

```
public static byte[] convertDocToByteArray(String sourcePath) {

    byte[] byteArray=null;
    try {
        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(sourcePath);


        String inputStreamToString = inputStream.toString();
        byteArray = inputStreamToString.getBytes();

        inputStream.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("File Not found"+e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("IO Ex"+e);
    }
    return byteArray;
}
```

If I use following code to convert it back to document, pdf is getting created. But it's saying `'Bad Format. Not a pdf'`.

```
public static void convertByteArrayToDoc(byte[] b) {          

    OutputStream out;
    try {       
        out = new FileOutputStream("D:/ABC_XYZ/1.pdf");
        out.close();
        System.out.println("write success");
    }catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

Comment: I have a similar queastion unable to open the pdf https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77823549/unable-to-generate-the-pdf-through-java

Answer (score 45):

Java 7 introduced `Files.readAllBytes()`, which can read a PDF into a `byte[]` like so:

```
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.Files;

Path pdfPath = Paths.get("/path/to/file.pdf");
byte[] pdf = Files.readAllBytes(pdfPath);
```

EDIT:

Thanks Farooque for pointing out: this will work for reading any kind of file, not just PDFs. All files are ultimately just a bunch of bytes, and as such can be read into a `byte[]`.

Comment: Thanks for the import edit @Farooque! What do you mean by "In general it can read a any given file into a byte[]"?

Comment: I tested pdf, jpg, gif, png, txt files which works perfectly. Since it supports all type of files, if someone need all types then "In general it can read a any given file into a byte[]" infomation will be helpful

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77823549/unable-to-generate-the-pdf-through-java pls check

Answer (score 34):

You basically need a helper method to read a stream into memory. This works pretty well:

```
public static byte[] readFully(InputStream stream) throws IOException
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    int bytesRead;
    while ((bytesRead = stream.read(buffer)) != -1)
    {
        baos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }
    return baos.toByteArray();
}
```

Then you'd call it with:

```
public static byte[] loadFile(String sourcePath) throws IOException
{
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    try 
    {
        inputStream = new FileInputStream(sourcePath);
        return readFully(inputStream);
    } 
    finally
    {
        if (inputStream != null)
        {
            inputStream.close();
        }
    }
}
```

*Don't* mix up text and binary data - it only leads to tears.

Comment: I guess there needs to be an extra bracket in readFully while statement .. like 

while ((bytesRead = stream.read(buffer)) != -1)

Comment: @JonSkeet - the size you initialise to is 8192 - how large of a PDF file would this work with? I know this is like asking *"How long is a piece of String"*, but maybe a generic guideline if you know? My PDFs will be up to 20 pages long at a guess.

Comment: @notyou: That's just a buffer size that isn't enormous, but is large enough to avoid "system call for each byte". It's a reasonable default, basically.

Comment: please see .. unable to open the pdf https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77823549/unable-to-generate-the-pdf-through-java

Answer (score 6):

You can do it by using `Apache Commons IO` without worrying about internal details.

Use `org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(File file)` which return data of type `byte[]`.

[Click here for Javadoc](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#readFileToByteArray%28java.io.File%29)

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me. I haven't used any third-party libraries. Just the ones that are shipped with Java.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class PDFUtility {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    /**
     * Converts byte stream into PDF.
     */
    PDFUtility pdfUtility = new PDFUtility();
    byte[] byteStreamPDF = pdfUtility.convertPDFtoByteStream();
    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\aseem\\Desktop\\BlaFolder\\BlaFolder2\\aseempdf.pdf");
    fileOutputStream.write(byteStreamPDF);
    fileOutputStream.close();
    System.out.println("File written successfully");
}

/**
 * Creates PDF to Byte Stream
 *
 * @return
 * @throws IOException
 */
protected byte[] convertPDFtoByteStream() throws IOException {
    Path path = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\aseem\\aaa.pdf");
    return Files.readAllBytes(path);
}

}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77823549/unable-to-generate-the-pdf-through-java pls see the same

Answer (score 2):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        File file = new File("java.pdf");

        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        //System.out.println(file.exists() + "!!");
        //InputStream in = resource.openStream();
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        try {
            for (int readNum; (readNum = fis.read(buf)) != -1;) {
                bos.write(buf, 0, readNum); //no doubt here is 0
                //Writes len bytes from the specified byte array starting at offset off to this byte array output stream.
                System.out.println("read " + readNum + " bytes,");
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(genJpeg.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        byte[] bytes = bos.toByteArray();

        //below is the different part
        File someFile = new File("java2.pdf");
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(someFile);
        fos.write(bytes);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
    }
```

Comment: please check .. unable to open the pdf https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77823549/unable-to-generate-the-pdf-through-java

Answer (score 1):

Calling `toString()` on an `InputStream` doesn't do what you think it does.  Even if it did, a PDF contains binary data, so you wouldn't want to convert it to a string first.

What you need to do is read from the stream, write the results into a `ByteArrayOutputStream`, then convert the `ByteArrayOutputStream` into an actual `byte` array by calling `toByteArray()`:

```
InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(sourcePath);
ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

int data;
while( (data = inputStream.read()) >= 0 ) {
    outputStream.write(data);
}

inputStream.close();
return outputStream.toByteArray();
```

Comment: Reading a single byte at a time isn't terribly efficient. Better to copy a block at a time.

Comment: @Jon - true, but I was trying to keep ti simple.  Also, doesn't FileInputStream do buffering internally anyways that would mitigate that?

Answer (score 1):

Are'nt you creating the pdf file but not actually writing the byte array back? Therefore you cannot open the PDF.

```
out = new FileOutputStream("D:/ABC_XYZ/1.pdf");
out.Write(b, 0, b.Length);
out.Position = 0;
out.Close();
```

This is in addition to correctly reading in the PDF to byte array.

Comment: out.position=0 ?? I dint get it

Comment: this may not have been useful as you are saving it to file but I ran into issues where I was putting the byte array into a MemoryStream object and downloading it to the client. I had to set the Position back to 0 for this to work.

Answer (score 1):

> To convert pdf to byteArray **:**

```
public byte[] pdfToByte(String filePath)throws JRException {

         File file = new File(<filePath>);
         FileInputStream fileInputStream;
         byte[] data = null;
         byte[] finalData = null;
         ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = null;

         try {
            fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            data = new byte[(int)file.length()];
            finalData = new byte[(int)file.length()];
            byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            fileInputStream.read(data);
            byteArrayOutputStream.write(data);
            finalData = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();

            fileInputStream.close(); 

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            LOGGER.info("File not found" + e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOGGER.info("IO exception" + e);
        }

        return finalData;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
try(InputStream pdfin = new FileInputStream("input.pdf");OutputStream pdfout = new FileOutputStream("output.pdf")){
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int bytesRead;
    while((bytesRead = pdfin.read(buffer))!=-1){
        pdfout.write(buffer,0,bytesRead);
    }
}
```

But Jon's answer doesn't work for me if used in the following way:

```
try(InputStream pdfin = new FileInputStream("input.pdf");OutputStream pdfout = new FileOutputStream("output.pdf")){

    int k = readFully(pdfin).length;
    System.out.println(k);
}
```

Outputs zero as length. Why is that ?

Answer (score 0):

None of these worked for us, possibly because our `inputstream` was `byte`s from a rest call, and not from a locally hosted pdf file. What worked was using `RestAssured` to read the PDF as an input stream, and then using Tika pdf reader to parse it and then call the `toString()` method.

```
import com.jayway.restassured.RestAssured;
import com.jayway.restassured.response.Response;
import com.jayway.restassured.response.ResponseBody;

import org.apache.tika.exception.TikaException;
import org.apache.tika.metadata.Metadata;
import org.apache.tika.parser.AutoDetectParser;
import org.apache.tika.parser.ParseContext;
import org.apache.tika.sax.BodyContentHandler;
import org.apache.tika.parser.Parser;
import org.xml.sax.ContentHandler;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

            InputStream stream = response.asInputStream();
            Parser parser = new AutoDetectParser(); // Should auto-detect!
            ContentHandler handler = new BodyContentHandler();
            Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
            ParseContext context = new ParseContext();

            try {
                parser.parse(stream, handler, metadata, context);
            } finally {
                stream.close();
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < metadata.names().length; i++) {
                String item = metadata.names()[i];
                System.out.println(item + " -- " + metadata.get(item));
            }

            System.out.println("!!Printing pdf content: \n" +handler.toString());
            System.out.println("content type: " + metadata.get(Metadata.CONTENT_TYPE));
```

Comment: Hi i have the similar question ...unable to open the pdf . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77823549/unable-to-generate-the-pdf-through-java

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented similiar behaviour in my Application too without fail. Below is my version of code and it is functional.

```
    byte[] getFileInBytes(String filename) {
    File file  = new File(filename);
    int length = (int)file.length();
    byte[] bytes = new byte[length];
    try {
        BufferedInputStream reader = new BufferedInputStream(new 
    FileInputStream(file));
    reader.read(bytes, 0, length);
    System.out.println(reader);
    // setFile(bytes);

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return bytes;
    }
```

Comment: hi i have the samilar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77823549/unable-to-generate-the-pdf-through-java

Answer (score 0):

```
public String encodeFileToBase64Binary(String fileName)
        throws IOException {
        System.out.println("encodeFileToBase64Binary: "+ fileName);
    File file = new File(fileName);
    byte[] bytes = loadFile(file);
    byte[] encoded = Base64.encodeBase64(bytes);
    String encodedString = new String(encoded);
    System.out.println("ARCHIVO B64: "+encodedString);


    return encodedString;
}

@SuppressWarnings("resource")
public static byte[] loadFile(File file) throws IOException {
    InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);

    long length = file.length();
    if (length > Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
        // File is too large
    }
    byte[] bytes = new byte[(int)length];

    int offset = 0;
    int numRead = 0;
    while (offset < bytes.length
            && (numRead=is.read(bytes, offset, bytes.length-offset)) >= 0) {
        offset += numRead;
    }

    if (offset < bytes.length) {
        throw new IOException("Could not completely read file "+file.getName());
    }

    is.close();
    return bytes;
}
```

Comment: I don't think the questioner needs a base64 conversion. He use `toString` just because he  doesn't know how to read the file to the bytes.

Comment: i have the same question unable to open the pdf in it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77823549/unable-to-generate-the-pdf-through-java

Answer (score -2):

PDFs may contain binary data and chances are it's getting mangled when you do ToString.
It seems to me that you want this:

```
        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(sourcePath);

        int numberBytes = inputStream .available();
        byte bytearray[] = new byte[numberBytes];

        inputStream .read(bytearray);
```

Comment: That's a horrible way of reading data - please don't assume that available() will contain all of the data in a stream.

Comment: @Jon - seconded.  available() will (usually) return the number of bytes that can be read immediately without blocking.  It has little to do with how much data is actually in the file..