# conver Binary data to PDF in C#

Tags: c#

How do I convert byte[] into a PDF document in C#?
I want to create a PDF file from the byte[] into c:/PDF/test.pdf

Comment: possible duplicate of [PDF to byte array and vice versa](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131116/pdf-to-byte-array-and-vice-versa)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way is using [`File.WriteAllBytes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writeallbytes.aspx):

```
File.WriteAllBytes(fileName, data);
```

No need for opening streams, worrying about closing them properly etc - it does it all for you.

That's assuming `data` already contains the PDF document appropriately, of course. If you haven't already got a PDF, you'll need to tell us what's in the `byte[]`...

Comment: What if i want to convert docx binary to pdf binary

Comment: @ammadkhan: Then that's a *completely* different question. (There's no real conversion going on in this question, despite the way it's phrased. It's just about writing the existing PDF to disk.)

Comment: can you plz guide how it can be done any link or source to solve this problem I am facing

Comment: @ammadkhan: No; please don't spam comment threads with unrelated questions.

Comment: I understand can you at least email me the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

If the data is already known to be pdf, it's simple.

```
System.IO.FileStream stream = new System.IO.FileStream(path, System.IO.FileMode.Create);
stream.write(data, 0, data.Length);
stream.Close();
```