# How to convert Byte Array to PDF file in Android?

Tags: java, android

I'm working on an application where i am getting the data in the form of byte array ,and i need to use this byte array for creating a new PDF file.How can i achieve this in android ?

Comment: Check this out: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131116/pdf-to-byte-array-and-vice-versa>

Answer (score 2):

Use [`FileOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html) and its `write(byte[])` method.

<sub># Assuming that you have data content which is ready to be writen in PDF.</sub>

There are also some pdf writers api available for android.

**See:**

- [Android pdf writer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/apwlibrary/)
- [How to create pdf on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2499960/how-to-create-pdfs-in-android-sdk)

Comment: Hi Jigar, I tried this code FileOutputStream fileos=new FileOutputStream("Hello.pdf"); 
but when I am trying to open this file,I am getting an error saying that Adobe Reader could not open Hello.pdf because it is either not supported file type or because the file has been damaged...

Comment: _Assuming that you have data content which is ready to be writen in PDF_ , See update

Answer (score 2):

Here is one of the way of creating **PDF** from **Byte Array**.

```
File dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File assist = new File("/mnt/sdcard/Sample.pdf");
try {
  InputStream fis = new FileInputStream(assist);

  long length = assist.length();
  if (length > Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
    Log.e("MainActivity", "cannnottt   readddd");
  }
  byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) length];
  int offset = 0;
  int numRead = 0;
  while (offset < bytes.length && (numRead = fis.read(bytes, offset, bytes.length - offset)) >= 0) {
    offset += numRead;
  }

  File data = new File(dir, "mydemo.pdf");
  OutputStream op = new FileOutputStream(data);
  op.write(bytes);
} catch (Exception ex) {
  Log.e("MainActivity", "" + ex.getMessage())
}
```

Comment: Correction in the above code is File assist=new File("/mnt/sdcard");

Comment: When i am trying to open this file i am an error saying that Adobe reader couldnt open the file because it is either not supported file type or because the file has been damaged.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Common IO](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/) library which will help convert simply from file to byte array or from byte array to file.

```
   File mFile = new File(filePath);
  FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(mFile, yourArray);
```