# Open file in some application via giving its byte array

Tags: android, file, android-intent

I have a byte array of a file. It is a pdf file. This file is not yet written to disk. I only have byte array of it. Is it possible to open this pdf file by using byte array in Adobe reader application without recording this byte array as a file on the disk.

Comment: You can find solution in possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8644459/how-to-convert-byte-array-to-pdf-file-in-android

Comment: I can save this byte array as a file. But my problem is to open without saving or making a new file in the directory.

Comment: Where do you think it must place? PDF file is not a variable, so you need to locate it somewhere, and then you can open it.

Comment: It should always stays in the ram. It should not be written to the disk. I must give my information to the receiving application without writing to disk. I must provide my file's information without writing to the disk.