# Can we use clob with Realm?

Tags: android, android-studio, realm, real-mode

New to Android and realm,
I have heard a lot  about using realm at the place of SQLite, But I want to store documents in Database. So Can we do it with Realm if yes then how can we do it?

Comment: What do you mean by documents? JSON?

Comment: Documents by mean that, text documents or PDFs , DOCs or any other document which can contain images + text

Comment: You can store blobs in Realm using `byte[]`. So yes, if you convert your PDF to a byte array it should work fine. There is a 16 MB limit on the blob though.

Comment: @Christian : can you please give me example or can you please share some link from where I will get more information

Comment: See e.g. here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131116/pdf-to-byte-array-and-vice-versa